# Dynamic, unpreditable sized array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, structure, dynamic-arrays

I am going to make an array of structure values.
The number of the entries depend on the input so there is no way to estimate the length of the array.

In a FOR loop, parsing the input, I would create an entry for every iteration.
That means I need to reallocate array because the size grows and this leads to inefficiency in terms of performance.

If I were allowed to program in C++, I would use vector. Unfortunately I can't, and I can't think of any better idea.

Please help me, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no way to estimate the length of the array, but do you know what the maximum length may be (i.e. is there a hard limit)?

Comment: No, I don't... Even worse, it is highly distributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I were allowed to program in C++, I would use vector.

Then you can do what `vector` would do: when you need to reallocate, double the size of the allocation. That should amortize `realloc` performance issues.

Comment: @downvoter: Thanks for the feedback! Would you mind leaving a comment to educate me on what is wrong in what I said ?

Comment: cnicutar: The question title and tags clearly states "C" not "C++". You are NOT answering "this" question hence the downvote.

Comment: @Adrian I *am* answering the question. I am simply stating a typical way of handling this problem in C that happens to emulate what the user is expecting from C++ . There is nothing C++-specific in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This article contains a complete solution for your problem. Basically it implements a "Vector" type class using C [Implementing a dynamically sized array in C](http://happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html)

It defines the vectory type like this:

```
// Define a vector type
typedef struct {
  int size;      // slots used so far
  int capacity;  // total available slots
  int *data;     // array of integers we're storing
} Vector;
void vector_init(Vector *vector);
void vector_append(Vector *vector, int value);
int vector_get(Vector *vector, int index);
void vector_set(Vector *vector, int index, int value);
void vector_double_capacity_if_full(Vector *vector);
void vector_free(Vector *vector);
```

There are similar questions already answered on Stack Overflow, have a look at them as well:

- [C resizing a dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847756/c-resizing-a-dynamic-array)
- [C dynamically growing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array)
- [resizing an array with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937409/resizing-an-array-with-c)

EDIT: Informative post on Wikipedia: [Dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

> In computer science, a dynamic array, growable array, resizable array,
>   dynamic table, mutable array, or array list is a random access,
>   variable-size list data structure that allows elements to be added or
>   removed. It is supplied with standard libraries in many modern
>   mainstream programming languages.
>
> A dynamic array is not the same thing as a dynamically allocated
>   array, which is a fixed-size array whose size is fixed when the array
>   is allocated, although a dynamic array may use such a fixed-size array
>   as a back end.

Comment: @FiddlingBits The complete solution is in the article.

Comment: You need to make a compromise between "Dynamic" and "Performance" - there is no such thing as a free lunch

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is NO better idea that what you suggested, C++ std::vector does exactly this under the hood (maybe with a more advanced estimation algorithm)

You simply need something like

```
typedef struct mystruct mystruct;
struct mystruct
{
 //Your struct's members
};

struct vector
{
mystruct* array;
unsigned dimension;
unsigned filled;
};

void vector_init(struct vector *v, int initial_size)
{
    v->dimension=initial_size;
    v->filled=0;
    v->array= malloc(sizeof(mystruct)*initial_size);
}

void vector_add(struct vector *v, mystruct obj)
{
   if(v->dim<=v->filled)
   {
       v->dimension*=2;
       realloc(v->array, v->dimension);
   }
   v->array[filled] = obj;
   v->filled++;
}

int main()
{
    struct vector *v;
    vector_init(v);
    mystruct struct_instance;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<whatever; i++)
    {
        insert_obj(array, struct_instance);
    }
    return 0;
}
```